# Partial HTML caching

Tags: html, json, caching

I have javascript code, which calls to server to get json and then generates HTML and append it to body tag:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/myController/myJsonMethod',
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
     },
     success: function (result) {
        var myHTML='<div>'+result.text+'</div>'+.....
        $( "body" ).append(myHTML);
     },
     async: true,
     processData: false
  });
```

This code is mostly static. The value of json result is changing couple of times in a year. Is there any way to cache this html part of the page?

Comment: If you are using HTML5 you could take advantage of the local Storage

Answer (score 0):

Caching the generated HTML hardly makes sense, since it is trivial. What *does* make sense is to cache the actual ajax request, which is a normal http request.

For that you the normal points apply that control caching of request results. Actually the default behavior is that such results *are* cached, unless you took special precautions to prevent that. Take a look at the http headers you send first.

However there is one issue with such strategy: even if the requests result changes only rarely, still you have to consider what actually happens in that case: if you cache the request, then the client is unable to see the change until the cache is outdated.

Comment: Hi, for static files I usually add header that cache expires 20 years from now. When static files change I rename it. That is the best possible option.
For ajax call this is not possible unless I change the name of my controller  method for every change. But it is ugly since it requires rebuild,...So, I thought to use eTag option - but it produce client requets every time. i guess there is no other way.